# How to use gomobile build sdk-arr-libs to access to web?

Tags: android, go, gomobile

I use `gomobile bind` generated an `.arr` file.

```
gomobile version
gomobile version +e154aff Wed Dec 2 14:48:43 2015 +0000 (android); androidSDK=D:\android\sdk\platforms\android-23

go version
go version go1.5.2 windows/amd64
```

Go code include a `func` which access to web.

```
client := &http.Client{}
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err.Error())
}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

I add this `.arr` to my Android project in `Android Studio`, build and install a apk to Virtual Devices.

But the app can't access to web.

After running app it comes out:

```
 GoLog: Get www.google.com: unsupported protocol scheme ""
```

I must missed something, please help me.

Comment: Sorry, such a stupid question asked by myself. The log just said scheme is    empty. I should use "http://" in the url "www.google.com".  In golang code, I test the `func` with correct url, and it works. In android project, the url is coming from user input. So, I should never ignore the log.  This thing bugs me all day until now , I saw the window clicked.

Answer (score 2):

It's nothing to do with `gomobile`. The url `www.google.com` should started with `http://`.